# How to get subspace of quantum circuit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state, matrix-representation

How can I get a subspace of a quantum circuit? More precisely, I'm dealing with quantum circuit with data qubits ('q') and ancilla qubits ('anc'), such as $(q_0,q_1,...,q_n,anc_0,..anc_m)$.

After some quantum operations, I'd like to get a unitary matrix representation of the data qubits. Is this possible?

Comment: welcome to the quantum computing stack exchange. If you are using Qiskit then this document might be helpful: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.partial_trace.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the partial trace of a density matrix, $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, where $|\psi\rangle=|q_0,q_1,...,ac_0,ac_1,...\rangle$. This matrix is surely a unitary matrix, and it can be viewed as a tensor product of all the density matrices of each qubit.

To get a subspace of a quantum circuit, you have to partial trace over all the irrelevant qubits, in your case, $Tr_{ac}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$.

If you are using `qiskit`, see the lower code as an example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit,QuantumRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix,partial_trace
import numpy as np
qr=QuantumRegister(2)
circ=QuantumCircuit(qr)
circ.h(qr[0])
circ.cx(qr[0],qr[1])
DM=DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ)
print(DM.data)
PT=partial_trace(DM,[0])
print(PT.data)
```

If you are not using the python package, and suppose you already got the density matrix of the entire quantum circuit, see the lower code(`qiskit` is again used to generate the density matrix, but I provide another function for partial trace in this place):

```
def partial_trace(rho,qubit2keep):
    num_qubit=int(np.log2(rho.shape[0]))
    for i in range(len(qubit2keep)):
            qubit2keep[i]=num_qubit-1-qubit2keep[i]
    qubit_axis=[(i,num_qubit+i) for i in range(num_qubit)
                    if i not in qubit2keep]
    minus_factor=[(i,2*i) for i in range(len(qubit_axis))]
    minus_qubit_axis=[(q[0]-m[0],q[1]-m[1])
                        for q, m in zip(qubit_axis,minus_factor)]
    rho_res=np.reshape(rho,[2,2]*num_qubit)
    qubit_left=num_qubit-len(qubit_axis)
    for i,j in minus_qubit_axis:
        rho_res=np.trace(rho_res,axis1=i,axis2=j)
    if qubit_left>1:
        rho_res=np.reshape(rho_res,[2**qubit_left]*2)
    return rho_res
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit,QuantumRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
import numpy as np
qr=QuantumRegister(2)
circ=QuantumCircuit(qr)
circ.h(qr[0])
circ.cx(qr[0],qr[1])
DM=DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circ)
print(DM.data)
PT=partial_trace(DM.data,[0])
print(PT)
```

(Note that the `partial_trace` function is a rewritten of [this one](https://gist.github.com/neversakura/d6a60b4bb2990d252e9e89e5629d5553), the default sequence in this code and mine are reversed.)

The two codes give identical results. In `PT=partial_trace(DM.data,[0])`, `[0]` denotes
the qubit to be traced out, maybe some test should be helpful for you to trace out the qubits that you don't need correctly.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment! It is what I'm looking for.